# The signal disappear after setting router as repeater

Tags: signals, repeater, router

I have a TP-LINK TL-MR3420 V2 router which I setup as a repeater. It works good for few hours (1-2) and suddenly the AP disappear from Wi-Fi list.

If I set the router as a normal router it works fine.

I don't understand what it's wrong with it. Can someone explain me what's the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check firmware on http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-MR3420_V2.html#Firmware

as well check your IP for the AP (Network -> LAN), it shouldn't be the same like the other router.